# problem installing sql 2005 related to msxml6

Tags: sql-server, installation, msxml

Sql 2005 client tools won't install due to a problem with msxml6

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\096825A1D2A65CB41B34C8A48E1DD969
```

from the registry

then reinstall MS SQL Server 2005

---

alternatively
Better is:
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, cmd, regedit

navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> enter 'msxml6'
then delete the key

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't even find the registry key mentioned in the accepted answer on my machine, but finally had success when I uninstalled MSXML6, reinstalled and then installed [Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML) 6.0 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d21c292c-368b-4ce1-9dab-3e9827b70604&displaylang=en)

For my machine (Windows XP) I selected the "msxml6_x86.msi" download.

Answer (score 0):

The long story: [Now we're getting somewhere : the MSXML6 issue](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/11/05/now-we-re-getting-somewhere-the-msxml6-issue.aspx).

The short story: download the [MSXML6 removal utility](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/3/F/E3F51FFB-505D-480E-9F67-0DD3A9680DEE/MSXMLFix.EXE), then install SQL Server 2005